# Creating a 3D Border for an ImageView in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimageview, border

I am working on an application which is used to change the orientation of the Image view and also provide a shadow to it. I have succeeded in that and the only obstacle remaining here is the fact that I have not been able to provide a 3D border to it as shown in this Image.

Look at the 3D border on the left and Bottom edge of this image view.
[image]

Please guide me to create this effect. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try CALayer's shadowColor with shadowOpacity, adjust shadowOffset to show the shadow in one side.

Comment: I have achieved the shadow effect. The only problem is to get the border as shown in the image above.